# Get the size of every GET

Tags: php, networking

I'm executing something like: `www.myserver.com/insert.php?name=alex&color=red&user=alex123`

How can I get the size of such a GET ? I mean, how many KB is traveling through the network? should I simply add the characters in 'alex','red', and 'alex123' ( 4 + 3 + 7 = 14 bytes ? )? Or is there anything else missing that I should add? Because i'm developing a mobile app and it should be efficient as much as possible especially that it will be using data connection for which charges may apply.

Comment: Do you care about the HTTP headers, or the response?

Comment: You could use wireshark to find out exactly what traffic this generates - you would be surprised how much "chatter" a simple GET causes.

Comment: All I'm doing is executing this http request, I'm not getting any response.( I mean I Don't care about getting any response)

Comment: Why aren't you interested in the characters in `name=`, `color=`, and `user=`? Those go over the network, too. And if you're trying to minimize traffic, you have more control over those (you could change it to `n=`, `c=`, `u=`).

Comment: If you don't care so much about the responses, you may want to use HTTP Head requests instead of HTTP get requests.

Here's an article on it: http://blog.mostof.it/what-is-a-http-head-request-good-for-some-uses/

Comment: Firebug or the developer tools built into Google Chrome browser  might give you the answers you're looking for.

Comment: being picky over a character here is there is okay if your dealing with millions of requests but ... there are better places to snip data then in the GET string if it improves readability for you and your developers